# Utf-8 create-scaffold-controller Grails

Tags: grails, utf-8

When I use create-scaffold-controller, Grails automatically apply latin-1 to MySQL column. Is there a way to make Grails use Utf-8 so that I don't have to log in MySQL and alter the column charset?

Answer (score 0):

This has *nothing* to do with the controller or the create-scaffold-controller script - the domain class defines the table struture. Grails doesn't choose any character set - this is defined by the default settings in your database. To see the generated table DDL run `grails schema-export` and look at `target/ddl.sql`.

It's simple to define a custom Dialect that specifies UTF-8 as the character set, for example http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/mysql-grails-and-utf-8-td2274498.html#a2274502

Or you could change the default at the databse.

Note that you should be using database migrations. e.g. http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration, and then you would be able to specify whatever you want.